# Traer datos desde una selección de combobox

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

Buenas tengo un problema al intentar traer datos desde una selección de combobox.
El programa consta de código y color. A cada código, un color. Y viceversa.
He puesto un combobox en el color que muestra los colores cargados, pero no logro que se inserte el código del color seleccionado en el entry de código.
¿Me podrían indicar qué estoy haciendo mal? He probado de varias maneras, pero siempre me arroja un error (que va variando de acuerdo a las alternativas que voy intentando).

Este es el código en cuestión:

```
from tkinter import Label, StringVar, Button
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
import sqlite3

def crear_base():
    base = sqlite3.connect("colores.db")
    return base

def crear_tabla(base):
    cursor = base.cursor()
    sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temples(codigo PRIMARY KEY, colores)"
    cursor.execute(sql)
    base.commit()

base = crear_base()
crear_tabla(base)

def agrega():
    cursor = base.cursor()
    data = (col.get(), descri.get())
    sql = "INSERT INTO temples(codigo, colores) VALUES(?, ?)"
    cursor.execute(sql, data)
    base.commit()

def combo_input():
    cursor=base.cursor()
    query = ('SELECT colores FROM temples')
    cursor.execute(query)
    data=[]
    for rows in cursor:
        data.append(rows[0])
    return(data)

def mostrar_colores(data):
    cursor=base.cursor()
    data = col.get()
    sql = ('SELECT codigo FROM temples WHERE colores=?')
    cursor.execute(sql, [data])
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    if result is not None:
        colores=result[0]
    col.delete(0, tk.END)
    col.insert(0, colores)
main_window = tk.Tk()
main_window.config(width=300, height=200)
main_window.title("Combobox")

codigo=StringVar()
colores=StringVar

co = Label(main_window, text="Código: ")
co.place(x=10, y=30)
col = ttk.Entry(main_window, textvariable= codigo, width = 9)
col.place(x=72, y=30)
desc = Label(main_window, text="Colores: ")
desc.place(x=10, y=50)
descri = ttk.Combobox(main_window, textvariable=colores)
descri['values']=combo_input()
descri.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", mostrar_colores)
descri.place(x=72, y=50)
btnagr = Button(main_window,bg="DarkOliveGreen2", text="Agregar color", command=agrega)
btnagr.place(x=73, y=85)

main_window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si entrar a valorar el resto del código, que probablemente podría ser mejorado, los cambios mínimos que necesitas hacer para que funcione se centran en la función `mostar_colores()`, en la que tienes mal lo siguiente:

- El color debes obtenerlo de `colores` y no de `col`, es decir, debes hacer `data = colores.get()`
- El resultado de la consulta SQL quieres asignarlo al `codigo` y no a `colores`, por lo que la asignación que tenías `colores = result[0]` es errónea
- Y de todas formas para cambiar el valor de una StringVar no se usa asignación, sino su método `.set()`, así que tu línea `colores = result[0]` debe ser `codigo.set(result[0])`
- Sobra la parte en que haces `col.delete()` y `col.insert()`

Es decir, la función queda así:

```py
def mostrar_colores(data):
    cursor=base.cursor()
    data = colores.get()
    sql = ('SELECT codigo FROM temples WHERE colores=?')
    cursor.execute(sql, [data])
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    if result is not None:
        codigo.set(result[0])
```

Además de eso, tienes un error en la línea que hacía:

```
colores=StringVar
```

pues estás asignando una clase, en lugar de una instancia. Debe ser así:

```
colores=StringVar()
```

Con estos cambios tu programa ya funciona, como demuestra la siguiente captura

[image: Captura]

### Extra

Cuando añades elementos con el botón "Añadir", se agregan a la base de datos, pero no al combobox. Una forma sencilla de arreglar esto es añadir la línea siguiente al final de la función `agrega()`:

```py
    descri['values']=combo_input()
```

Otra mejora opcional es que `combo_input()` retorne los valores por orden alfabético, para que sean más fáciles de encontrar para el usuario al desplegar la lista. Es tan sencillo como cambiar el return de esta función por `return (sorted(data))`

Comment: Solo quiero aclarar, que si estás trabajando con consultas sql, estas tienen el order by, que seguramente sea más rapido y más claro que usar sorted en Python.